# Can You Apply Laplacian deform to a Hooked Path?

Tags: modifiers

I'm doing a kind of object transferring from one box to another and both box will be moving WHILE the objects inside is transferring to another.
How do you do this?

Comment: i intend the Laplacian deform to morph the path nicely between the two boxes, and also can this link of boxes by path still work once i apply an array after it? (transfer object from many boxes to one box)?

Comment: also is there a better way of doing what i want to do here?
like logically in the BGE for example, the object will move between the boxes on a wavy/spiral line not straight?